# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of null error on vanilla js but not in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, typeerror

I have two pages, `page1.html` & `page2.html`, they link to the same javascript file.
This is the markup for page 1

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

    <button class="button">HIT ME</button>
    <div class="trig"></div>
</body>
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
</html>
```

and page 2

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <button class="button_2">HIT ME</button>
</body>
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
</html>
```

and this is the script

```
document.querySelector(".button").onclick = function(){
    document.querySelector(".trig").style.display = "block";
}
```

When I refresh page 2 I get

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of null error

obviously because it can't find the `.button` class

But when I write the same thing in jquery it runs gracefully with no errors in both pages.

```
$('.button').click(function(){
    $('.trig').show();
});
```

I want to understand why this happens and how to write the same thing in vanilla js without getting any errors.

Comment: there is no element with the class `.button` on your second page

Comment: how a '.button_2' is getting clicked if it's not there?

Comment: Did you read the second part of the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to understand why this happens and how to write the same thing
>   in vanilla js without getting any errors.

Because when the element with `button` class doesn't exists, then `$('.button')` doesn't return null, while `document.querySelector(".button")` does.

You need to check for null first with vanila js apis

```
var button = document.querySelector(".button");
button && ( button.onclick = function(){
    document.querySelector(".trig").style.display = "block";
});
```

Comment: I tried your solution but I'm getting `Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment`

Comment: @Jay Sorry, I have updated the answer. Just had to wrap the second part in braces.

Answer (score 0):

When the page load starts it will execute the code that is in JS. Trying to execute `document.querySelector('button') ...` at this moment will fail because the document (DOM) has not yet been done (parsing), so it does not have the button element yet.

This has two solutions:

1. Use the defer in the `<script>` tag. That will tell the browser to execute the JS after the () of the whole page.

   ```
   <script src="script.js" defer></script>
   ```
2. Grab the `<script src="script.js"></script>` and put in before the end of the `</body>` tage. With this, the JS will only run after the page is complete.

Answer (score -1):

because you write it in wrong way.

you should use it like

```
$('.button').on("click", function(){
    document.querySelector(".trig").style.display = "block";
});
```

Comment: I don't want to combine jquery and plain javascript.